# resetting SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, reset

I have a button that appears at the end of my app when the game is complete that is meant to reset the app. I have tested it and it works besides the timer. I have does not reset to the "startTime". I have a button that is used to reset the game such as:

```
if(resetButton.getText().equals("Restart"))
{
    reset_flag = true;
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

I have a runnable for the timer as:

```
long gamerestart = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
if(reset_flag)
{
    gamerestart = 0;
    startTime = 60000;
    flag = false;
}
timeInMilliseconds = startTime - gamerestart;
```

The `reset_flag` did help as I noticed the time at the top of the game reset to the original time but at the next time-tick it updated to whatever the `currentThreadTimeMillis` is.
I did try doing `SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() = 0;` but that did not work ( I was not surprised it didn't either..)

I did not see a function within `SystemClock` that would doing any resetting. I thought this would be a simple task but maybe it is not, could anyone give me some help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That time is how long the thread has been alive, consider using a separate variable for timing. You can always initialize it to SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() and deduct SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() whenever you want to display the value

Comment: Perhaps I was not very clear before.  I have a timer counting down at the top of the screen and when I hit startActivity(i) the timer is not being reset to a minute.  Everything else is reset besides the timer.